# Create Azure Data factory Linked service to SQL Managed Instance

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-sql-managed-instance, linked-service

I want to store data in a SQL managed instance database using azure data factory
in this case, I have to create a linked service to this database
but I get an error and I don't know how to go through

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mGAo.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing code that reproduces the problem would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message it seems that you are leveraging Private end point
So you need to leverage Fully qualified domain name as the public endpoint shown in networking page and not the host name

Comment: Hi

I resolved my problem by creating a managed endpoint network in Data Factory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal-private#create-a-managed-private-endpoint

thanks to all of you for your help